# Sum data table columns using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datatable

Hi all I am having my data in datatable as follows

```
SKU  Quantity  UnitPrice  LinePrice
 A     10         2         20
 A     10         2         20
 B     10         2         40
```

I would like to sum up the SKU with duplicate records and get the result as follows

```
SKU  Quantity  UnitPrice  LinePrice
 A     20         2         40
 B     10         2         40
```

I tried this but no luck

```
var query = from row in lDTSalesOrder.AsEnumerable()
                            group row by row.Field<string>("SKU") into grp
                            orderby grp.Key
                            select new
                            {
                                Id = grp.Key,
                                Sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("UnitPrice"))
                            };
```

Comment: Why do you make lDTSalesOrder an enumerable if you're querying the database?

Comment: What's the problem? I executed your code, and it returned the valid results.

Answer (score 4):

In your sample output you haven't actually summed the Unit Price, but it sounds like what you want is something like this:

```
var results = 
    from row in lDTSalesOrder
    group row by row.Field<string>("SKU") into grp
    orderby grp.Key
    select new
    {
        SKU = grp.Key,
        Quantity = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("Quantity")),
        UnitPrice = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("UnitPrice")),
        LinePrice = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("LinePrice"))
    };
```

This will produce:

```
SKU  Quantity  UnitPrice  LinePrice
 A     20         4         40
 B     10         2         40
```

---

If you really want to produce a Unit Price of `2` for the first result record, `Sum` is not what you want; you'll have to to use some other aggregate function. `Min`, `Max`, `Average`, or even `Select(...).First()` would produce that result, but you'd have to more precisely define what you want in your output. You could also do this:

```
var results = 
    from row in lDTSalesOrder
    group row by new { SKU = row.Field<string>("SKU"), UnitPrice = row.Field<string>("UnitPrice") } into grp
    orderby grp.Key.SKU
    select new
    {
        SKU = grp.Key.SKU,
        Quantity = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("Quantity")),
        UnitPrice = grp.Key.UnitPrice,
        LinePrice = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("LinePrice"))
    };
```

Any of these options will produce:

```
SKU  Quantity  UnitPrice  LinePrice
 A     20         2         40
 B     10         2         40
```

Comment: the UnitPrice isn't supposed to be summed

Comment: @lisp It's not clear how to handle `UnitPrice`, but I've tried to add several solutions which produce OP's sample output.

Comment: Hi I am getting an error as `could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.DataTable'.  'GroupBy' not found.`