# datatable colum sum using linq in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Here is my first datatable dt

```
sscode  scons  cscons  cstagged
  A      10         2         20
  A      10         2         20
  B      10         2         40
```

Here is my second datatable dt1

```
Unit  sscode
A101     A 
A101     A
B101     B
```

and i want this output

```
Unit  scons  cscons  cstagged
A101     20      4         40
```

I'm getting error while executing this query.
Here is my code

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> result = from data1 in dt.AsEnumerable() 
                             join data2 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                             on data1.Field<string>("sscode") equals
                             data2.Field<string>("substation_code")
                             group data2.Field<string>("Unit") by new {unit= data2.Field<string>("Unit")} into grp
                             orderby grp.Key.unit
                             select new
                                 {
                                     unit = grp.Key.unit,
                                     sscons = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<string>("cscons")),
                                     cscons = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<string>("cscons")),
                                     cstagged = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<string>("cstagged"))
                                 };
                             result.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Can you share error message?

Comment: error in the case the (s => s.Field<string>("cscons"))  
 s does not contain a defination for  '<Field>'

Comment: Are you calculating sum of string?

Comment: yes but i dont know in datattable by default which datatype is there

Comment: By default datatype of datatable is DataTable.

Comment: okay thanks for reply but can you solve my issue

Comment: @Harshal - It's really hard to understand what you are trying to do. Share some sample input and output what you are expecting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499218/sum-data-table-columns-using-linq this is same like me but i have two datatables

Comment: @Harshal - Yeah exactly share some sample data like other question.

Comment: Question is updated

Comment: @Harshal : is the B101 required in the output?
check this https://dotnetfiddle.net/feUMdX

Comment: yes all unique unit

Comment: check this https://dotnetfiddle.net/feUMdX

Comment: @Harshal the query in fiddle gives you required output

Comment: thanks bro for your effort but i don't know something is wrong in my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135576/discussion-between-chintan-udeshi-and-harshal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that `grp` holds the collection of both dataTables in which case you won't be able to get the items from first DataTable directly.

If I have understood your question correctly then this should give you the expected output:-

```
var result = from data2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() 
             group data2 by data2.Field<string>("Unit") into g
             select new { Unit = g.Key, dt2Obj = g.FirstOrDefault() } into t3
             let filteredData1 = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Where(x => x.Field<string>("sscode") == t3.dt2Obj.Field<string>("sscode"))
             select new
                   {
                       unit = t3.unit,
                       sscons = filteredData1.Sum(s => s.Field<int>("cscons")),
                       cscons = filteredData1.Sum(s => s.Field<int>("cscons")),
                       cstagged = filteredData1.Sum(s => s.Field<int>("cstagged"))
                   };
```

First we  are grouping by `Unit` in second dataTable (as that is the grouo which we need) then we are projecting the the entire object to get the `sscode` by using `FirstOrDefault`, after this simply filter the first list based on value we got from grouped `sscode` and project the items.

Check [Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JlCtu6).

Comment: @Harshal - You cannot project an _anonymous type_ to datatable directly. You will have to implement a cusom type as mentioned in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096(v=vs.100).aspx) or [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/convert-linq-query-result-to-datatable/). BTW can you let me know why you need a _DataTable_ ?

Comment: sum of sscons and below are not performing

Comment: @Harshal - Not performing as in? Any error you are getting? I have tested it on my system and it's working fine for me.

Comment: @Harshal - I don't know where you are getting the error , please check the fiddle which I've just added to see where you are wrong.

Comment: Sum(s => s.Field<int>("cstagged")  Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: @Harshal - Are you adding data in _cstagged_ as string? Can you check the fiddle which I've added?

Comment: @Harshal - Okay Harshal, have you checked my Fiddle? You can see that working right? Can u please compare it with your code?

Comment: when the result is inserted to datatable units are inserted but the others 3 columns are getting 0 values and finally specified cast error occurs

Comment: @Harshal - Cast expection would only occur if you have dataType other then `int` and you knw `0` is not a string, so you have some other error. I gave you the exact working sample but I am not sure if you have compared it.

Answer (score 1):

First, You have to select after the group by otherwise only the grouped field is selected.
Second, You cannot sum strings. Only numeric fields (int, double...)

I'm not fluent in the inline-linq syntax, so I've changed it to methods chain.

```
var result =
dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Join(dt1.AsEnumerable(), data1 => data1.Field<string>("sscode"), data2 => data2.Field<string>("substation_code"),
        (data1, data2) => new {data1, data2})
    .GroupBy(@t => new {unit = @t.data2.Field<string>("Unit")}, 
        @t => @t.data1)
    .Select(
        grp =>
            new
            {
                unit = grp.Key.unit,
                sscons = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<int>("sscons")),
                cscons = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<int>("cscons")),
                cstagged = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<int>("cstagged"))
            });
```

*Note: Be aware that from this query you cannot use `CopyToDataTable`*

**Update**
Since i understand that your fields are stored as strings you should use `Convert.ToInt32`:

```
grp.Sum(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Field<string>("cscons"))
```

**Update 2**
As per the chat - it seems that the values are decimal and not ints:

```
 sscons = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<decimal>("sscons")),
 cscons = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<decimal>("cscons")),
 cstagged = grp.Sum(s => s.Field<decimal>("cstagged"))
```

Comment: giving error Specified cast is not valid for Sum(s => s.Field<int>("cscons")),

Comment: Well, what type are these fields? if it's really strings than you have to parse into ints. But it's best to have them stored as int in the first place. Will update my answer to add a convert to int

Comment: i have added column in datatable are DataTable data = new DataTable();
            data.Columns.Add("Unit", typeof(string));
            data.Columns.Add("sscons", typeof(int));
            data.Columns.Add("cscons", typeof(int));
            data.Columns.Add("cstagged", typeof(int));

Comment: And it still gives you `Specified cast is not valid`?

Comment: @Harshal something is strange. `Unit` is not in the same table as `sscons` and `cscons` but in your comment above it seems you add thest fields to the same DataTable

Comment: First, Have you tries the `ConvertToInt`? Second, see my previous comments about the wrong fields in the wrong datatable

Comment: when the result is inserted to datatable units are inserted but the others 3 columns are getting 0 values and finally specified cast error occurs

Comment: I'm sorry but this just not the way that linq and datatables work.  You have to specify the correct type in your source datatable or use convert them as i mentioned before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135605/discussion-between-harshal-and-ofir-winegarten).